# Is it possible to Rewire castle's candle brackets?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does rewire mean in this context:

> After the castle’s candle brackets were all rewired, the king put in
> energy-saving light bulbs.

If there were candles before, then there were no wires. Then how can they RE-wire (as in wire again)?

it's from the book called "The Unofficial Harry Potter Vocabulary Builder" and all the information they provided on the matter in the book is this:

> **bracket** (brak-et)
>
> noun A fixture protruding from a wall or column to hold a lamp,
> candle, torch, or sign. / Chamber of Secrets, page 139
>
> After the castle’s candle brackets were all rewired, the king put in
> energy-saving light bulbs.

Comment: Why couldn't they have been first wired 50 years ago, and are only now being rewired?

Comment: Oh God! Harry Potter again! Do NOT expect good writing from those books.

Comment: You don't need new wiring to use energy-efficient bulbs. I daresay JK Rowling is not an electrician.

Comment: Once they were wired for electrical bulbs, they weren't candle brackets any more, so it should be *wired*.

Comment: Some electric light fittings are designed to _look like_ candles or oil lamps. Maybe the reference is to these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means "put in new wires".  Yes it might logically incorrect, and perhaps a mistake, but it is a mistake of fact, and not a mistake of grammar.

It seems a common enough use.  Here is a picture of a gas light "[rewired for electricity](https://www.flickr.com/photos/11236515@N05/22023931305)"...Well I know that it means that the gas pipes have been replace with cables, so its not real **re**wiring.  But I don't think that there is any doubt about the meaning.